# Is there a service that provides Battle.NET badges to include in web pages?

Tags: starcraft-2, battle.net

StackOverflow (and associated sites), offers badges you can embed on any web-page. It's available through the user page on the ["flair" tab](https://gaming.stackexchange.com/users/10051/exhuma/flair).

I wonder if something like this is available for Battle.NET. Either by Blizzard directly (preferred), or by a third party.

Alternatively, I could scrape the default pages for results, but an official API would be cleaner.

I ask this because I am currently building a small local community. So far, we have a small wiki up and running, and I'd like to have one page listing all players, their current avatar and rank. Showing them off as a properly styled badge would be awesome.

Comment: This is  a good question... but I'm on the fence as to whether on not it should be considered on-topic for gaming.SE - it seems like it's more of a question for SO or web applications.

Comment: @Wip, IMO, the question about whether battle.net has this functionality or not is on-topic. Were he to ask how to scrape the site, it'd be a different story.

Comment: @Juan-Manuel - I agree that a "question about whether battle.net has this functionality or not is on-topic", but he's asking for an API as well. Which is a technical question, not a gaming one.

Comment: @Wipqozn: I agree that this is a bit controversial. I wasn't sure where to ask at first. I was about to ask it on SO, as that is anyway my most active account on StackExchange. But in the end I came to the same conclusion as @JuanManuel: It's not about *how* to do it, but more a general inquiry about existing Battle.NET services.

Comment: https://develop.battle.net/

Answer (score 4, accepted):

I believe they do not offer this.

Sites like [SC2Ranks](http://www.sc2ranks.com) for example, scrape the battle.net public profiles in order to generate their statistics.

Your best bet would be to do that, or even check [their API](http://www.sc2ranks.com/api) out to see if you can skip that step and take advantage of their work (of course, this is starcraft 2 specific, but there may be similar things for other games that I don't know about)

Comment: Great. This looks very promising. I'll keep the question open for a short while. If nothing better creeps up. I'll accept it ;)

Answer (score 4):

I think what you are looking for is [this website](http://sc2.jimluc.com/).

It generates images like this:

[image]

Comment: Yes, this is exactly what I am looking for. Unfortunately I am quite picky about design. And well... what can I say... These badges are not quite tickling my tastebuds... ;) Still. Thanks a lot for your answer.

Answer (score 0):

Adding this answer so as to be comprehensive. It looks like there IS another site, http://sc2sig.com/ that a lot of people were using, particularly as per [this TeamLiquid forum thread](http://www.teamliquid.net/forum/viewmessage.php?topic_id=136683) started in 2010. However, that site appears to be broken as of August 2012. No word on whether it will be fixed or not.

HOWEVER: On http://sc2.jimluc.com/ that @Opera mentioned, there appear to be some other features that were either missed before or have been added since then. After you create your badge, just choose from the 7 different tabs on the result page to get the link for the style you want.

For example:

[image]
<sub>(source: [jimluc.com](http://sc2.jimluc.com/11494-1.png))</sub>

<sup>(Woo wood league :P)</sup>

One more important note: on that site, you link to your profile using your battle.net profile link, however, stats for the badge are pulled from sc2ranks.com, so there is a delay in when things get updated.